# Preventing Users from Downloading file from website directly, how?

Tags: asp.net

I need very advanced and effective method of Preventing Users from Downloading file from website directly in asp.net.

Method should -

limit downloads,
 limit time,
 limit requests,
 etc.

**but should be downloadable by active login users**

Comment: You'll need to provide a very detailed scenario to get any sensible answer. Provide all the relevant details so as to help people provide useful answers. As it stand currently, the answer to your question is - don't put the file on the server - that way no one can download it.

Comment: any type of file (.zip, .exe, .msi, .rar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the files in a folder which is not accessible via IIS (i.e., not underneath your web application's root)

Create an .ashx generic handler which takes a file identifier (either filename, or ID of some sort) as a QueryString parameter.

In that .ashx, perform whatever checks you want to perform: is the user logged in? have they downloaded too many files? etc.

Then, if you decide that they *should* be allowed to download it, set the response headers appropriately and write the file out to `Response.OutputStream`

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file from the server.

Any user trying to download it will not longer succeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your files into a directory and configure that directory as not accessible by public users.

Comment: but non-public users are grouped (free, normal, power)

Comment: one option could be to create nested directories.

For example, create a directory named "free_user_files". Inside this directory create another directory "normal_user_files". 
And inside the "normal_user_files", create another directory named "power_user_files".

Then do the following:

a) Give all the 3 groups, access to the "normal_user_files"
b) Give only normal & power users, access to the "normal_user_files"
c) Finally, give only power users, access to the inner most directory "power_user_files".